# how can I execute requests within a for loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array with requests.

```
request = ['request1', 'request2','request3',...];
```

I want to execute this http requests and obtain the values.

I do:

```
var values = [];
     angular.forEach(requests, function (value, key) {
        mymethod.then(function(value){
            values.push(value);
        };
    });
console.log(values);
```

Problem, values contain always different length. I imagine that the array is executing without waiting to mymethod return anythig, because is asynchronous method.

How can I have the correct values array containing all the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that requests are asynchronous, so you need to wait until they are all completed.

As requests are promises you could use promise.all method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

So code would look something like this:

```
var values = [];
var promises = [];
angular.forEach(requests, function (value, key) {
    promises.push(mymethod.then(function(value){
        values.push(value);
    });
});
Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have [async await support in your environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) you can use that or you can use a library to group your async methods and execute them in parallel or serial like https://caolan.github.io/async/

Here is how to send a bunch of requests with the library in the link in parallel and print the json results after all of them are obtained

```
async.parallel(
  urls.map(function(url) {
    return function(callback) {
      fetch(url).then(t=>t.json()).then(callback);
    };
  ), 
  function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
  }
);
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more your answer who seems good? For example what's the fetch method? I'm using angulsJS 1, I think the arrow functions will not work